# Updating data for new added column in database , code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backend, code-first

I have an existing table for Users in my database that contains around one million record . my database is MS sql server 2016 . I am working code first . Now I will add an additional column for that table which will contain an invitaion code . 
I need to update the value of all existing users to have a unique invitaion code for that new column. 
I need to make something that will run one time only (may be in the seed method) as this data will be updated and any new user will be created in future will have its invitaion code while registering .

So this will be applied for old users , what is the best way to do that regarding the performance and speed and i have too much records in that table , is it seed method that will run at start of the app or what ?

Comment: You should include a version number of your database in your solution so when you update (add a column) you have an indication if the database has the new column.

Comment: Does the `invitation code` have some format or it can be a number from 0 to 9999999?

Comment: yes the invitation code has a formate , it should be a string of length 6 char mix of digits and numbers and it should be unique for each user

Comment: How many records in the `Users` table?

Comment: one million record

Answer (score 1):

I think a script SQL  would be the best solution, you run it ones and you are done.

A seed method would be a solution if you are in early development mode, so you may delete records and re-run the seed method, but if your database is stable a script would be better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a migration with the added column (you'll have to mark it as nullable)

2) Create another migration where you

Populate the column with whatever values you want.
You do this by adding a custom sql statement

`Sql(@"UPDATE YourTableName set YourColumnName = insert logic here")`

3) Create another migration modifying the column to be non-nullable.

You may be able to add the custom sql statement at the end of the first migration or the beginning of the last migration.